# HTML isn't interpreted correctly when injecting '<br>' strings into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml, line-breaks

```js
'use strict';                                     

function injectCharacters(){
  var paragraph = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' ),
      text = paragraph.innerHTML,
      ary = text.split( '' ),
      i = 1;
  
  paragraph.innerHTML = '';
  
  for ( i; i <= 52 ; i++ ){
    window.setTimeout(
      ( 
        function( i ){ 
          return function(){
            paragraph.innerHTML +=  ary[ i ];
          }
        } 
      )
      ( i ), i * 100 
    )
  }
}

injectCharacters();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p {
  margin: auto;
}
.mtx-3d {
  transform:
    perspective( 10rem )
    matrix3D( 
      1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0075,
      0.25, 2, 2, 0.02,
      1, 2, 3, 4,
      1, 2, 3, 0.75 
    )
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="mtx-3d">
  So. Yeah I mean. <br>I've been thinking <br>A lot
</p>
```

In the snippet above the line breaks are literal in the output. I want an actual line-break to display instead of seeing `<br>`. How can I solve this simple problem?

I suspect it has something to do with me breaking up every character into a value housed in an array then outputting that back to the paragraph element but I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't actually see your code injecting `<br>` tags into inner HTML.  Where is this supposed to be happening?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the <br> are coming from the element's html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The original paragraph element has the `<br>` tags in them. I'm splitting it's `innerHTML` content into an array, then injecting that back out into the element again one array value at a time. After the timeout.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate, but did you step through your code with a debugger and check what character might be coming through as a line break?  Check the first line of the paragraph up until the end of the line.  What final character(s) do you see where you would expect a `<br>` to have been in the original HTML?

Comment: You are correct in thinking that concatenating the html 1 character at a time is what is causing problems. it is going to see `<` with nothing else when it is entered and from then on it is going to treat it as that character and not a token representing the start of an element tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Using a debugger this is what I see in the `innerHTML`: http://i.imgur.com/71fSbWl.png. Literal `<br>` strings.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Any simple way to fix this or would I have to re-engineer the bulk of the code, you think?

Comment: Perhaps I don't follow correctly, but could you not just replace `<br>` with a newline `\n` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll try it in a fiddle and post here but I'm thinking wont it just be output in the HTML like the `<br>`s were. Like as literal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By appending a new character every time, with `innerHTML +=` the browser will convert `<` and `>` characters as HTMLEntities, and thus the sequence `<br>` will be converted to `&lt;br&gt;` :

```js
para.innerHTML += '<';
console.log(para.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

To fix it, you can set the current content every time with `innerHTML =  text.slice(0, i);`.

```js
'use strict';                                     

function injectCharacters(){
  var paragraph = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' ),
      text = paragraph.innerHTML,
      i = 1;
  
  paragraph.innerHTML = '';
  
  for ( i; i <= 52 ; i++ ){
    window.setTimeout(
      ( 
        function( i ){ 
          return function(){
            paragraph.innerHTML =  text.slice(0,i);
          }
        } 
      )
      ( i ), i * 100 
    )
  }
}

injectCharacters();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p {
  margin: auto;
}
.mtx-3d {
  transform:
    perspective( 10rem )
    matrix3D( 
      1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0075,
      0.25, 2, 2, 0.02,
      1, 2, 3, 4,
      1, 2, 3, 0.75 
    )
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="mtx-3d">
  So. Yeah I mean. <br>I've been thinking <br>A lot
</p>
```

And if you don't want to show `<`, `<b` and `<br`, you could replace it in your string before hand to some unlikely to show up character, and replace it again when setting :

```js
'use strict';                                     

function injectCharacters(){
  var paragraph = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' ),
      text = paragraph.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, '\u10FF'),
      i = 1;
  
  paragraph.innerHTML = '';
  
  for ( i; i <= 52 ; i++ ){
    window.setTimeout(
      ( 
        function( i ){ 
          return function(){
            paragraph.innerHTML =  text.slice(0,i).replace(/\u10FF/g, '<br>');
          }
        } 
      )
      ( i ), i * 100 
    )
  }
}

injectCharacters();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p {
  margin: auto;
}
.mtx-3d {
  transform:
    perspective( 10rem )
    matrix3D( 
      1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0075,
      0.25, 2, 2, 0.02,
      1, 2, 3, 4,
      1, 2, 3, 0.75 
    )
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="mtx-3d">
  So. Yeah I mean. <br>I've been thinking <br>A lot
</p>
```

Comment: Great insight. Your example still doesn't work but I'm trying out your suggestion on my own.

Comment: @basement which browser?

Comment: Chrome but you didn't update the javaScript to reflect `innerHTML =  text.slice(0, i);` in the ex, did you? What line did you fix this on. I don't see it and snippet not working.

Comment: @basement yeah something weird did happen there... fixed

Comment: This is good. This is very good now I will try to eliminate the less than sign that shows up for a split second. If I can fix it with this technique I'll accept.

Comment: @basement I've addded this too

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
'use strict';                                     

function injectCharacters() {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph'),
      text = paragraph.innerHTML,
      i = 0;

  paragraph.innerHTML = '';

  while (i < text.length) {                                 
    var c = text.charAt(i);
    if (text.slice(i, i + 4) == '<br>') {
        c = text.slice(i, i + 5);
    }
    window.setTimeout(function( c ) { 
        return function() {
          paragraph.innerHTML += c;
        }
      }( c ), i * 100 
    ); 
    i += c.length;
  }
}

injectCharacters();
```

I basically re-worked the logic to check for 
`'<br>'`. 
If found, append it plus the next character.  This seems to preserve the 
`<br>` element in the html.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the html element away into it's own element so it will end up like

```
["a,"b","c","<br>","d","e","f"]
```

You could for instance loop over each node of the element, split all textNodes and when it sees a element just add the element's html.

```
Array.from(paragraph.childNodes).forEach(function(node){
  if(node.nodeType == 3){
    ary.push( ...node.textContent.split('') );
  } else {
    ary.push( node.outerHTML );
  }
});
```

Note this example will probably only work well with elements that don't have sub elements like a div with children. And if your paragraph ends up containing more complex html than just `<br>` it will probably need refactoring.

Demo

```js
'use strict';                                     

function start(){
  var paragraph = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' ),
      ary = [];
  Array.from(paragraph.childNodes).forEach(function(node){
    if(node.nodeType == 3){
      ary.push( ...node.textContent.split('') );
    } else {
      ary.push( node.outerHTML );
    }
  });

  paragraph.innerHTML = '';
  
  for ( let i=1; i < ary.length ; i++ ){
    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
      paragraph.innerHTML +=  ary[ i ];
    }, i * 100);
  }
}

start();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p {
  margin: auto;
}
.mtx-3d {
  transform:
    perspective( 10rem )
    matrix3D( 1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0075, 0.25, 2, 2, 0.02, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0.75 )
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="mtx-3d">
  So. Yeah I mean. <br>I've been thinking <br>A lot
</p>
```

Comment: Another great solution. Thank you.